# ¿Cómo formular este código de forma sintácticamente correcta en PHP?

Tags: php

Me está dando error de sintaxis, me gustaría saber como formular esta código de forma sintácticamente correcta:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=999; $i++) {
     if (isset($_POST["item_name$i"])) {
         echo "$item_name$i = $_POST['item_name$i'];";
     }
}

for ($j=1; $j<=999; $j++) {
     if (isset($_POST["quantity$j"])) {
         echo "$quantity$j = $_POST['quantity$j'];";
     }
}
```

Básicamente quiero hacer un `for` loop como parte de un listener de Paypal en el que me cree automáticamente las variables con la información de los productos que ha comprado el cliente,

si se recibe un `$_POST` no vacío de Paypal arrancando desde `['item_name1']` hasta `['item_name999']`, en plan:

```
$item_name1 = $_POST['item_name1'];
$item_name2 = $_POST['item_name2'];

/*etc.

siempre que se cumpla el isset(); */
```

¡Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error y en qué línea te lo manda tu intérprete de PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te lo da al tratar de llamar a una variable `$_POST` dentro del string. Eso porque `$_POST` es un array y no puede ser "volcado" dentro de un string.

Para estos casos, puedes usar las llaves `{}` al referirte a un valor que pertenece a un array.

```
echo "$item_name$i = {$_POST['item_name$i']};";
```

Si modificas tu código agregando estas llaves ya no te aparece el error de sintaxis.

Comment: Correcto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda! :)